# How to Query Using a Model that Belongs To Itself in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 3.2. I have a setup similar to the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :is_admin
  belongs_to :created_by, :foreign_key => :created_by_id, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

This works if not using ActiveRecord query, just like the following:

```
#rails console
User.first.created_by.is_admin
#=> true

#But I want to query like the following, but it doesn't work
User.where(:created_by => {:is_admin => true})
#ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'created_by.is_admin' in 'where clause'...

#This also doesn't work:
User.joins(:created_by).where(:created_by => {:is_admin => true})
#ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'created_by.is_admin' in 'where clause'
```

I would really be grateful for any help.

Comment: `User.includes(:created_by).where(:created_by => {:is_admin => true})`

Comment: `includes` instead of `joins` also didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using 2 queries

```
admin_ids = User.where(:is_admin => true).pluck(:id)
@users = User.where(:created_by_id => admin_ids)
```

I'd do this because

- A lot of times, 2 simple queries are faster than 1 complex join query
- Readable & easy to understand

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, in my code I really needed it as one query only because it is a nested query. 
Like: users = ... \n users = users.where(...) But if there is no really simple way, I guess I'll just do the hard way like the one you suggested.

Comment: Oh wait. I think it's still possible to do the two queries even if using nested queries... Thanks, I'll try if it's gonna work.

Comment: `admin_ids` is a separate query. `where(:created_by_id => admin_ids)` can be chained on